# Manipulating a map to hide and show elements depending on the zoom level

Tags: d3.js

Disclaimer: I'm an absolute d3.js n00b. I'm beginning to become proficient in JavaScript, but d3.js is giving me a bit of a headache.

I've a project I want to do, quite similar to [The Art of Asking](http://www.theartofasking.com). I have a lot of data to show - I have to go down to the parliamentary/congressional district level for a few countries, not just provinces or states - and trying to load all the SVG elements kills a few lower-end computers I've been testing the project on. I rather would like it if I didn't explode any computers. (Actually, I'm pretty sure not exploding computers is a requirement of my project.)

To work around this, I figure that doing a hide/show mechanism like The Art of Asking is the path of least resistance, but while I can figure out how to hide an element, I haven't a clue how to show it after it's been hidden. I think creating a map that acts like a collapsible tree would be similar to what I want to do, but I could also just be going in the wrong direction entirely.

Comment: how are you hiding the elements? If you are tracking the zoom level can't you just show the level of geography for that level? Like in your link.